# Move link to the end of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

```js
$('container a').appendTo('.container');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <p>dzedzdqdqdqzdqdzqdzqdqzdqd</p>
    <a class="forgot_password" href="#">Forgot password</a>
    <p>dedededededededededede</p>
    <p>dzedzdqdqdqzdqdzqdzqdqzdqd</p>
</div>
```

I want the link at the end of `.container` like this

- Paragraph 1
- Paragraph 2
- Paragraph 3
- Link

I try this line of jquery but it does not work

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the `.` in first selector `$('container a')`, change it to `$('.container a')` because `container` is class for parent `div` and your code will work

```js
$('.container a').appendTo('.container');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <p>dzedzdqdqdqzdqdzqdzqdqzdqd</p>
    <a class="forgot_password" href="#">Forgot password</a>
    <p>dedededededededededede</p>
    <p>dzedzdqdqdqzdqdzqdzqdqzdqd</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.insertAfter()` this way:

```js
$('.forgot_password').insertAfter('.container p:last');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>dzedzdqdqdqzdqdzqdzqdqzdqd</p>
  <a class="forgot_password" href="#">Forgot password</a>
  <p>dedededededededededede</p>
  <p>dzedzdqdqdqzdqdzqdzqdqzdqd</p>
</div>
```